# How to remove new Vue in /.quasar/client-entry.js?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

With firebase, because of its life cycle, firebase.auth().currentUser is always null when refreshing app or website. 
So I want to store Vue somewhere and not draw when site refreshed just like below.

```
// boot/auth.js 
import Firebase from 'firebase'

export default ({ app, router, Vue, store }) => {
  let appTemp
  Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(=> {
    if (!appTemp) { // <<- draw vue only appTemp doesn't have to prevent refresh website.
      appTemp = new Vue(app) 
    }
  })
}
```

it works only if I remove new Vue like this in /.quasar/client-entry.js

```
  if (routeUnchanged === false) {
    return
  }
  // new Vue(app)
}
start()
```

but client-entry.js file re-made automatically when quasar has started.
How can I remove or prevent new Vue in quasar?
I want to make it manually.

Comment: You definitely don't want to touch `.quasar/client-entry.js` to maintain something in your app.  Are you sure re-authenticating with Firebase is not a better option?

Comment: Thank you for reply, when the page refreshed, there is still no way to prevent see login page, now I have changed vue cli instead, and changed it manually.